# Video/audio chat programs that offer end-to-end encryption that do not let the service know of the content?

Tags: video, audio, chat, encryption

Skype is compromised, FaceTime is compromised, and I believe Ovoo is compromised.  Does anyone know of any genuinely free (not free-to-try or in-app purchase-type applications) that offer end-to-end encryption for video and audio chat?

Ease of use is not of concern, only that the program(s) fulfill(s) the requirements above.

If there are none that are free, I suppose it is okay to answer with subscription or paid services that fulfill these requirements.

Answer (score 3):

**[tox](https://tox.chat/about.html)**:

> Tox began a few years ago, in the wake of Edward Snowden's leaks
>   regarding NSA spying activity. The idea was to create an instant
>   messaging protocol that ran without any kind of central servers. The
>   system would be distributed, peer-to-peer, and encrypted end-to-end,
>   with no way to disable any of the encryption features; at the same
>   time, the protocol would be easily usable by the layperson with no
>   practical knowledge of cryptography or distributed systems. Work began
>   during the Summer of 2013 by a single anonymous developer (who
>   continues, to this day, to remain anonymous). This lone developer put
>   together a library implementing the Tox protocol. The library provides
>   all of the messaging and encryption facilities, and is completely
>   decoupled from any user-interface; for an end-user to make use of Tox,
>   they need a Tox client. Fast-forward a few years to today, and there
>   exist several independent Tox client projects, and the original Tox
>   core library implementation is nearing completion (in terms of
>   features). Tox (both core and clients) has thousands of users,
>   hundreds of contributors, and the project shows no sign of slowing
>   down. Recently, a group of some of the project's major contributors
>   have formed The Tox Project, an organization built around the
>   protection, promotion, and advancement of Tox and its development.